# RestAPI, using '/' in params

Tags: rest

If I have

```
GET /api/product/:path
```

And do a request:

```
GET /api/product/http://otherapi/params/format=json
```

This will not work. How do I encode my path so it will work?

Comment: You url-encode the :path you're sending (in this case, as `http%3A%2F%2Fotherapi%2Fparams%2Fformat%3Djson`). What language are you using to formulate your request? Many have a `urlencode` or similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode your character in the url, with `/` being `%2F` in the url. [Here is encoding reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

In your example it would work like this:

```
GET /api/product/http:%2F%2Fotherapi%2Fparams%2Fformat=json
```

Comment: I updated my question. Could you update the answer with my example?